# How to specify which format resharper autocompletes arrays?

Tags: c#, resharper

I do a lot of array based coding in C#. Resharper (a great tool) does one quirky thing when autocompleting arrays. It thinks I want this after pressing tab to auto-complete:

```
int[] foo = new[] {};
```

when I really want this:

```
int[] foo = new int[];
```

If I wait for intellisense I can see the second option:

[image]

Is there a way to either completely remove that first option, or, to set the preference for the second option when I press tab to auto-complete?

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question, but I have used Jetbrain's support quite a few times and found them to be extremely helpful. Why not ask them? http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/anonymous_requests/new

Comment: @Avrohom: Thanks for the link. I sent in a support request. I'll post back the answer here if I ever get one. In the meantime, if anyone else knows the solution please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer provided by Jetbrains support:

"I believe there's no way to configure this behavior. Though, you may create a custom Live Template for these needs. You may read more about Live Templates here: https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Templates__Applying_Templates__Creating_Source_Code_Using_Live_Templates.html?search=Live%20Templates

Hope it helps.
Thanks.

Senior Support Engineer
JetBrains
http://www.jetbrains.com
"Develop with pleasure!"